# How to grep kubectl output to the Jenkins variable

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, groovy

I have kubernetes job and I would like to get his pod logs in the jenkins pipeline.

So I try to grep pod name to the jenkins variable and then get logs.

```
POD_NAME = sh script: "kubectl describe jobs.batch ${JOB_NAME} | grep 'Created pod' | cut -d':' -f2"

echo "${POD_NAME}"

sh "kubectl logs --follow ${POD_NAME}"
```

But I got `null` in the `POD_NAME` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your jenkins controller or agent is able to query the kubernetes api with kubectl because it has a serviceaccount or some other form of credential to access kubernetes.

If that is true, I propose that you use a label to identify the pods created by the job and to query anything related to them.

You can do that by adding a label to the `.spec.metadata.labels` section as shown below and then query with kubectl and the `--selector` flag:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: MYAPP
  ...
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      ...
      labels:
        test: value
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: MYAPP
        image: python:3.7.6-alpine3.10
        ...
```

`kubectl logs --follow --selector test=value`

Use `kubectl logs --help` to get further information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

stage('Check pod status'){

```
  steps {

      script{

          sh '''

          POD_NAME=$(kubectl describe job -n ${NAMESPACE} ${JOB_NAME} | grep Created | cut -d ':' -f2)

          echo "${POD_NAME}"

          '''
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).